# Implementing Spring MVC Controller using annotation as well as implementing Controller

Tags: spring-mvc

This may be trivial. But I didn't get any info on this.

Can we have an annotated Controller implementation class and a Controller implementation class that implements Controller interface(or extends AbstractController) in the same web application?

If so what is the way to do it.

I tried writing the following spring context, but the class that implements Controller was never loaded

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">



    <bean name="/home.htm" class="com.dell.library.web.HomePageController">
        <property name="library" ref="library" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dell.library.web.anot" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

In my case the HomePageController is never loaded. 
Is this the right way?

Thanks 
Dhanush

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<mvc:annotation-driven>` effectively disables old controllers. You need to enable them by declaring

```
<bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />
<bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter" />
```

**UPDATE:** Functionality of `DispatcherServlet` is controlled by sevaral kinds of strategy classes. In particular, `HandlerMapping` defines a way to map URLs onto controllers, and `HandlerAdapter` defines a way to perform a call of particular controller.

So, lines above declare strategies that enable mapping URLs onto bean names and calling `Controller` classes. Actually, there strategies are enabled by default, but only if no other strategies are declared explicitly. Since `<mvc:annotation-driven>` declares in own strategies explicitly, you need to declare these beans explicitly as well.

Also see [`DispatcherServlet` javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html).

Comment: Thanks. That Worked. What does those two entries do in this case?

Comment: @Bozho - I could't upvote it since I didn't have enough reputation (15 is needed to upvote). I am a newbie in SO

Comment: @dhanush yes, I'm aware of that, don't worry. That's why I upvote it :)